# REGEXP_SUBSTR in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to remove Remove the string after the pipe separator. In oracle
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(KEYVALUES,'[^|]+',1,1) from tab1;
Please help in converting this in postgeSQL?

```
000000001
000000001|16
000000002
000000002|16
000000003
000000003|16
000000004
000000004|16
000000005
000000006

o/p
000000001
000000001
000000002
000000002
000000003
000000003
000000004
000000004
000000005
000000006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part()`

```
select split_part(keyvalues, '|', 1)
from ...
```

Alternatively you can use a regex with the `substring()` function:

```
substring(keyvalues from '[^|]+')
```